# Bigcommerce api for Best product and top deals

Tags: bigcommerce

Is there any API does Bigcommerce provides for the best products and top deals. I only got the featured product when I pass is_featured as param in
https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/********/v3/catalog/products get API.

Answer (score 2):

If by "best products" you mean highest selling, you could do that with `/v3/catalog/products?sort=total_sold&direction=desc`

I'm not sure of a way to do "top deal" if you mean biggest difference between sale and RRP